# Return city and state based on zip code

Tags: javascript, lookup-tables

I would like "city" and "state" to appear on screen based on what "zip code" user has typed into a text box. I have a 3 column text file of the zip, city and state.  What is the most efficient way to structure the javascript function to do this?

Comment: Is your data loaded anywhere, or are do you also need the answer to somehow grab the data from the text file? How is the data formatted? Comma delimited? Tabbed? Piped?

Comment: For starters make sure that the file is on the client so you don't have to keep making expensive ajax requests to check against the file

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Comment: I think Google Geocode API is best for my needs. I plan on capturing the zip code using the text box and button below. However how do i tell javacript to append the text box entry, for example "10128", to the URL: 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=10128&sensor=false

    <input type="text" id="user_enters_zip" />
    <button id="request_citystate" value="Get City State" />

Answer (score 0):

Preprocess your text file into a JSON object of the form

```
{
    "10461": { City: "Bronx", State: "NY" }
    ... 
}
```

If you are really lazy you can use [d3.nest](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_nest) to do this directly from the text file. However, it would be great for your clients if you did it once and just stored the JSON rather than having each client load the text file and do it repeatedly.

Once you have that, it's easy...just read the JSON object, and index into it using the ZIP code, and grab the city/state.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to define a server function that will return the city and state in JSON based on a zip code. 
2) Subscribe to change, keyup and input events on an input field.
3) Define a JavaScript function that will call the server function using AJAX. On the success function, you set the fields using the response.

I'm pasting the client-side code below:

```
$("#txtZipCode").bind("change keyup input", function (e) {
        var field = $(this);
        if (field.val().length === 5) {
            showLocation(field.val());
        }
        else
            showLocation("");
    });

function showLocation(zipCodeValue) {
    var txtCity = $("#city");
    var txtState = $("#state");
    if (zipCodeValue.toString().length != 5) {
        txtCity.val("");
        txtState.val("");
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "Location/GetZipCode",
            data:
                {
                    zipCodeNumber: zipCodeValue
                },
            success: function (data) {
                    txtCity.val(data.City);
                    txtState.val(data.State);
            }
        });
    }
}
```